# OnItemClickListener vs OnclickListener in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

This is gonna be long due to code. So I have a question about OnItemclickListener vs OnclickListener,and here I have two codes one for each and both worked, so is there any preference to use one of the two or can I use anyone???
Here is code with OnItemClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> numbers=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //a listview with id "list"

        ListView numberLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        numbers.add("one");
        numbers.add("two");
        numbers.add("three");
        numbers.add("four");
        // and so on
        listAdapter itemadapter=new listAdapter(this,numbers);
        numberLV.setAdapter(itemadapter);
        numberLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String num=numbers.get(position);
                String display="You have clicked "+num;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,display,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
class listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public listAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> numbers){
        super(context,0,numbers);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_num, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tvnum=(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.numbersTV);
        String num=getItem(position);
        tvnum.setText(num);
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

and here's one with OnClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> numbers=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //a listview with id "list"

        ListView numberLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        numbers.add("one");
        numbers.add("two");
        numbers.add("three");
        numbers.add("four");
        // and so on
        listAdapter itemadapter=new listAdapter(this,numbers);
        numberLV.setAdapter(itemadapter);
    }
}
class listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public listAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> numbers){
        super(context,0,numbers);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_num, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tvnum=(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.numbersTV);
        String num=getItem(position);
        tvnum.setText(num);
        listItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String display="You have clicked "+getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),display,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Both codes worked normally for me, but the confusion was whether the second one was right or wrong??

Comment: Both are technically correct, `setOnItemClickListener` would be the preferred method as it returns adapter information outside your adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adapter

The `setOnItemClickListener` is the preferred way of attaching the click listener on the items of the adapter as mentioned by the first comment above.

### View

In your second scenario, where you have  `setOnClickListener` attached on individual item inside the `getView` method which is also valid because the ItemView in this case is an *indirect subclass* on [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) on which `setOnClickListener` originally declared.

Answer (score 2):

I think setOnItemClickListener() is the best than onClickListener() because,

1. It give you a single row click in activity or fragment where ListView defined.
2. It is easier when you want to perform operation on onItemClickListener() such as open another activity or fragment.
3. We can get selected row List object using view.getTag() method in on item click method.
4. When you have call data from web api like soap or restful on listview item click then it is easy way to implement it.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have the OnclickListener on getView, in this way, if more than one class is using theadapter then, we only need to define OnclickListener in adapter only

Comment: Yes, in above situation it is ok.